# Remote Push Notification badge count not increasing when app is in background

Tags: ios, background, push, badge

I am working on remote push notification and getting badge count in payload. it's working fine when my app is active(foreground) but when app run in background and i got push then badge count not increases. Please help.

when app is active it calls `didReceiveNotification` method.

I am receiving this type of info in payload.

```
{aps = {alert = "Hi all.";badge = 6;sound = default;};}
```

I am not sure where is issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = xx, in -applicationWillEnterForeground: or -applicationDidBecomeActive: And one more thing it will not increase, normally badge count maintained at servers you can update badge value in code by using [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = xx

Comment: Hi
Thanks for quick response. i am doing following code in didReceiveRemoteNotification. 
        
int badgeCount = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount;


Please can you tell me what to do with this. I am confused because every one says that it will autoincreament by os according to APNS server response.

Comment: Hi
Thanks all
I got the issue. It is from server side. actually badge should be an integer value. but due to unknown reason it is considering as a string.

Comment: Hi you can check this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/23948633/2246798

Comment: I received push notification in all state i.e. when app is in forground, background, close(terminated)..!
but my problem is that how to increment badge count when app is in background state and close (terminate) state???? 
Please tell me in details how i do it....?
my app badge count is only increase when app is in forground state.....?

if possible please tell me in brief.......!SWIFT 3

Comment: Badge count is come from backend. So you need to keep count of badge in backend.
When you open the app you have to set it 0 and with API call it will be reset in backend and start from 0 again.
There is a payload format your backend dev use to send badge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllNotifications];
}
```