# How to increase badge number when application is in background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using this code. Every thing is working fine when push notification comes but badge number does not increase when application is in background. How to solve this problem?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    //UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSInteger badgeNumber = [application applicationIconBadgeNumber];// Take the current badge number
    //badgeNumber--;    // decrement by one
    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[[launchOptions valueForKey:@"aps"]valueForKey:@"badge"]integerValue]];  // set ne badge number

    NSLog(@"userInfo :%@  %d",launchOptions,[[[launchOptions valueForKey:@"aps"]valueForKey:@"badge"]integerValue]);


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You have to track the badge number on the server. There is no way to auto increment the number through a push notification. Would be amazing if Apple could add the functionality.

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/23948633/2246798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the application is in the background `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method never calls. For doing something when your App is in background you need to implement your logic in `AppDelegate's` `applicationDidEnterBackground`: method like.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 2;
}
```

Comment: I am getting badge number from server, How can increase when push notification comes?? I want to do like whats app.

Comment: Ok got it, I was facing the same scenario I fixed that by through the notification below is my code may it will help you: NSDictionary *userInfo = [responseObject objectForKey:@"unread_notifications"]; [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(newNotification:)
                                                 name:@"unread_notifications" object:nil];

Comment: -(void)newNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userInfo] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        _notifiImageView.hidden = YES;
        _notificatinLbl.hidden = YES;}
    else{_notifiImageView.hidden = NO;
        _notificatinLbl.hidden = NO;
        _notificatinLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userInfo]; 
        NSString * badge = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userInfo];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge.intValue;
    }}

Comment: Please let me know if you have any other question?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't increase the badge number using code when app is in background or closed state**.**But the badge can be increased by value in notification payload**.No code will execute during this state and Push notification is handled by OS itself.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117430/pushwhoosh-remote-notification/26119399#26119399) have the same issue and resolved.

Check whether the push notification payload contains application badge field and set to values greater than 0.If its 0,then badge number will be 0 when app in background or closed.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a Push Notification you need add badge value. So you need handle badge for each user device. In php is something like that:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge'=> 10
);
```

where 10 thats just the number displayed in the icon.

Answer (score 0):

**You can increase badge number when your app is in background.**

Write didReceiveRemoteNotification function to App Delegate and add 1 to application.applicationIconBadgeNumber

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification
                userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

// increase badge count, but no need if you include content-available
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1 }
```

---

**You can also reset badge number when app become active.**

Write applicationDidBecomeActive function to App Delegate and make application.applicationIconBadgeNumber to 0

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 }
```