# Pushwhoosh remote notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pushwoosh

We used Pushwhoosh for remote notification. Its working fine but Icon badge count not increased.

Here is code:

```
- (void) onPushReceived:(PushNotificationManager *)pushManager withNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushNotification onStart:(BOOL)onStart
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];

     PushNotificationManager * pushManager = [PushNotificationManager pushManager];
    pushManager.delegate = self;

    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        PushNotificationManager * pushManager = [PushNotificationManager pushManager];
        [pushManager startLocationTracking];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```

How to increase app Icon badge count upon push delivery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution. We have option to set notification badge number in push whoosh server.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It is a *badge number issue* from server side.Check whether the push notification payload contains application badge field and set to values greater than 0.
       Because when the application is closed/in Background,the value in notification payloads is used to set badge in default by iOS and not the value in your code.Your code will set badge only when the application is running state.In your case,most probably the badge value passing in payload will be 0.

Comment: Didn't get it. You mean we need to do something in push whoosh server side notification message? I set it in onPushReceived, so its no effect ?

Comment: I mean when the app is closed or in Background,the value we are setting in onPushReceived will not work because the method will not be invoked.The value is set by notification payload.

Comment: notification payload means message sent from push whoosh server right. So we need to contact push whoosh server.

Comment: Yes.But before that you can debug and check the payload first.Simply set an alert to read the pay load content.If the badge field is 0,then definitely its payload issue.

Comment: got solution, we have option in push whoosh server. http://i.stack.imgur.com/9eNGR.jpg  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome Gururaj.Could you please up vote my answer.Thanks