# AppDelegate is not listening to APNS Push Notification

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, ios8, apple-push-notifications

When my app enters background, AppDelegate is not listening to the new push notification from APNS. But strange thing is that it doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. I can't figure out why.

Here is my sample code for listening APNS Notification

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:nil];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Received notification background: %@", userInfo);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       // Check result of your operation and call completion block with the result
                       completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
                   });
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In background/closed mode,no code will execute and none of the delegate method will be invoked.This time push notification is handled by OS itself.The app badge is set by push notification payload value coming from server side.
**If you are not getting app badge in background,it is a badge number issue from server side.Check whether the push notification payload contains application badge field and set to values greater than 0.**

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117430/pushwhoosh-remote-notification/26119399#26119399) have same issue and resolved it.

Comment: the server side sent the notification with content-available: 1 and app should grab the data from server. However, didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called - but it doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes, it works. I don't understand this. Btw thank you for your reply.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification will call only when the app is in running state and no code executes in background state.How you understand sometime its working?

Comment: i put the log line in applicationDidEnterBackground so that i'd know when the app enters background state. And also there is a log line in didReceiveRemoteNotification to print the notification, i can see the notification in the logs sometimes.

Comment: Anyway didReceiveRemoteNotification will not execute when app is in bg.But it will invoked when you are tapping on notification from notification tray (so app will launch automatically).May be this is your case..PLease let me know why you want to write code in didReceiveRemoteNotification for background case so that i can point out the issue.

Comment: thanks. if thats a case, i need to figure out alternative to trigger the notification from server. any advice ? thank you.

Comment: I didn't get you what really you want to do.If notification badge is missing when app in bg,may be the issue is badge field in notification payload will be 0.set it a value greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your line..

```
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

in iOS 8 you have to use "UIUserNotificationTypeBadge"...

Hope this will work for you..