# How to handle App Icon Badge Count on receiving push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to increase the badge count when a notification is received and decrease when user tap or open the app.

I also try this code  but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: what doest your push notification aps dictionary contains?

Comment: `{
"aps" : {
    "badge" : 9
}
}`

Comment: then you can use this value..! and when your app become active set badge count 0

Comment: No this is just the example but in place of 9 it is always showing 1

Comment: you have to take this value here ("badge"), because you can not modify the badge value when you app is in state quite/background: refere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117430/pushwhoosh-remote-notification/26119399#26119399

Comment: But this value can be incremented from web services, so there is no option to increment it .

Comment: whatever the value comes in "aps" object ,I have to take that value

Comment: Yes, increment this from web service, when when app become active set it to 0. iOS handle this badge value automatically!

Comment: There might be another solution to increase this value without using web service. But thank you for your valuable answer and time.

Comment: your welcome, i will also search and reply you!

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge application is showing number as badge count which is sent by you in this { "aps" : { "badge" : 9 } } dictionary as badge value.

What you are setting in this method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; 
}
```

is set when you open application by tapping on remote notification which is logically not write because when you are opening application that time you are setting badge count.

You must have to pass badge value in your aps dictionary and you may reset badge count when application opened (in didFinishLaunchingwithOption method).

Apart from this, there is no method you can write in your application code that set badge count as soon as you receive push notification and your application is already in kill mode(not open at all).