# how show the Push notification Count In App in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using firebase notification it's working fine, when application in foreground I want display the remote notification count in App, 1 :when I can get message notification I have to show the remoter notification count.

from my payload badge count always sending 1 only,

[image: image here]

how can I show notification count?

Comment: you have to set badges in your push notification payload.Look at thsese links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372548/how-to-handle-app-icon-badge-count-on-receiving-push-notification

Comment: @Gagan_iOS is there any possible to increment  count of the notification in app

Comment: You have to use a badges. also you can get badge count from push notification pay-load.

Comment: @NilayShah when application in foreground I'm getting the notification how to show that count in my app, badge number I m getting how to diplay that number in my app when application in foreground

Comment: @Dhruv first get badge count either your app is foreground or background. set badge count in your global variable. now in the same `UIViewController` set this count to your badge control.

Comment: @NilayShah in background badge count  when user tap the banner, how can in foreground when the application using how can I get count

Answer (score 0):

For push notification you have to write the logic on server.
When server send the notification to the particular device it also send badge count with payload.
IOS OS automatically update your app icon with badge count.

Comment: I want display the count inside my application

Comment: When you get notification then below function will be called.
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Answer (score 0):

Do below steps:

1. Get final badge count from push notification payload.
2. Save this count to your project global variable. (From any where you have to access it.)
3. When you want to display a badge count at the same place give this variable value to badge.

For getting badge count from payload, please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256852/1746086) link.

Comment: how to Get final badge count from push notification pay-load

Comment: Are you getting any badge count in push notification payload?

Comment: yes am getting always count 1 from server side its showing

Comment: AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = " You got a message ";
    badge = 1;
    sound = default;
},

Comment: This 1 (badge = 1) you have to parse from notification payload and store in global variable. It will be working fine.